# 2013 Putnam A1 Proof understanding (geometry)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, geometry, contest-math

Problem A1:

> Recall that a regular icosahedron is a convex polyhedron having 12 vertices and 20 faces; the faces are congruent equilateral triangles. On each face of a regular icosahedron is written a non-negative integer such that the sum of all $20$ integers is $39.$ Show that there are two faces that share a vertex and have the same integer written on them.

Beginning with a contradiction. Suppose there aren't two faces that touch one vertex. Each vertex has $5$ faces attached to it. Hence the $5$ take on different values (since they are touching each other). The least possible is: $$0, 1, 2, 3, 4$$ For corresponding sides such that another side touching cannot have the same value. So for example

[image: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/IcosahedronNet_500.gif]

If I have $5$ faces abcde, on the side of $e$ there is a different face (not part of the original 5) that cannot take on the value of $e$.

Hence,

$$a + b + c + d + e = 0 + 1 + 2+ 3 + 4 = 10$$

Same for the other 15 faces, the least becomes $40 > 39$.

Here is my problem.

> I don't see this properly. If two faces did have the same number with the same vertex, how would that have changed the sum from $40$? Can somebody give me an example of the original statement of the problem for an intuitive understanding?

Thanks!

Comment: If faces sharing a vertex could have the same label, then you could just write $0$ on each face and get a label sum of $0$.  With the constraint as given, the average label around each vertex must be at least $2$; hence the average label overall must be at least $2$; hence the label sum must be at least $20\times 2 = 40$.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative answer. I don't think it answers your specific question about the existing proof.

Consider the set $P$ of pairs $(f,v)$ of faces and vertices on the face. Let $n(f)$ be the number written on the face.

Let $$S=\sum_{(f,v)\in P} n(f)$$

Counting by each face we get:

$$S=\sum_{f} 3n(f) = 3\cdot 39$$

Counting by each vertex, we get:

$$S=\sum_{v} \sum_{f\mid(f,v)\in P} n(f)$$

But you've shown that $\sum_{f} n(f)\geq 10$.

Since there are 12 vertices, this means that $S\geq 120$.

This is a contradiction, since $3\cdot 39<3\cdot 40=120$.

More generally, if $G$ is any trianglulation of the sphere, then we can define $P$ again ad we get:

$$\sum_f n(f) \geq \frac16\sum_{v} d(v)(d(v)-1)$$

where $d(v)$ is the degree of the vertex - the number of edges incident with the vertex.

For example, if you triangluate each of the faces of the icosahedron by adding one node internally, you end up with 12 nodes or degree $6$ and 20 nodes of degree $3$. So you have as lower bound a sum:

$$\frac 16\left(12\cdot 30 +20\cdot 6\right)=80$$

You can definitely do better than that - $90$ is a better lower bound. easily proven.

That doesn't mean you can achieve this value - the value for the tetrahedron by this formula, with $4$ nodes each of degree $3$, would be $\frac{1}{6}\cdot 4\cdot (3\cdot 2)=4$, while the actual minimal value is $6$.

It does come up with the exact right answer for the octahedron of $12$.

Comment: I like the proof, I just need help understanding it =) Perhaps you can answer a question or two? 

$$S=∑(f,v)∈Pn(f)$$
Counting by each face we get:

$$S=∑f3n(f)=3⋅39$$

I do not understand the transformation to $3 \cdot 39$? How did you get that?

Comment: Because $\sum_f 3n(f)=3\sum_f n(f)$ and we assumed $\sum n(f)=39$. That is an assumption of the problem. @Lebes

Comment: Yes, but why are you trying to find $$\sum 3n(f)$$??

Comment: Oh, because for fixed $f$, $\sum_{v} n(f)=3n(f)$, since every face has exactly three vertices (since every face is a triangle.) So if we do $\sum_{(f,v)} n(f)$ by summing over the the faces then over the vertices incident with that face, you get: $$\sum_f \sum_{v\text{ incident with }f} n(f)$$ and the internal sum, for any $f$, is just $3n(f)$. @Lebes

Comment: BTW, if you were only confused about the first part, why did you include the second part? Try to concentrate on the part that is confusing you, so I don't end up explaining the part that you understand.

Comment: thanks. The vertex doesnt have a number on  it though? So what would summing the vertices get you?

Comment: For each vertex on $f$, we add $n(f)$. This value doesn't depend on the vertex, which is why we get $3n(f)$. It's really a very simple argument. @Lebes

Comment: mmm. I am confused. I just need to understand one thing, which the root of the problem: How is the relation:

$$\sum_{(f,v)\in P} n(f) = \sum_{f} 3n(f)$$

Established?

Comment: @Lebes. Don't overthink it. It's $$\sum_{(f,v)\in P} n(f)=\sum_{f} \sum_{v\text{ on }f} n(f) = \sum_f 3n(f).$$ More generally, if there was some function $g$ define on $P$, you'd have: $$\sum_{(f,v)\in P} g(f,v)= \sum_{f}\sum_{v\text{ on }f} g(f,v)$$ That gives the first equality. The second equality is due to the fact that $n(f)$ does not depend on $v$, and the number of terms in the internal sum is always $3$.

Comment: There's a rigorous argument for this - you are picking a particular order to do the sum on $P$ here. A rigorous proof of the general approach would not give you a lot more clarity. It might be worth drawing a table of the same $P$ for an octahedron. Write it as a grid of $8$ rows, one per face, and $6$ columns, one per vertex, and write $n(f)$ in only the boxes that correspond to the cases when $v$ is on $f$. If you want to sum all the values in these boxes, you can add the rows first, and, for each row $f$, there will be three values on that row, all equal to the same value, $n(f)$.

Comment: You'll get a table that looks like $$\begin{pmatrix}n(f_1)&n(f_1)&n(f_1)&&\\n(f_2)&&n(f_2)&n(f_2)&&\\n(f_3)& & &n(f_3)&n(f_3)&\\n(f_4)&n(f_4)&&&n(f_4)&\\&n(f_5)&n(f_5)&&&n(f_5)\\&&n(f_6)&n(f_6)& &n(f_6)\\& & &n(f_7)&n(f_7)&n(f_7)\\&n(f_8)&&&n(f_8)&n(f_8)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Summing each row gives $3n(f_i)$, so the total is $3\sum_i n(f_i)$. Each column has to be at least $6$, since all the faces in each column have to have different values, and the least would be some order of $0,1,2,3$.  So the sum of all these values is at *least* $6\cdot 6$ - six columns, each of total at least $6$. This gives us that $\sum_i 3 n(f_i)$ - the sum of the values done by row first - is at least $36$, which means $\sum n(f_i)$ is at least 12.

Comment: okay, that's a lead. Lets take the sum you wrote on the RHS step by step. What does just:

$$\sum_{v\text{ on }f} n(f)$$

Mean?

Comment: That means, in the diagram above, the sum of the values on the row corresponding to face $f$. Do you know the $\Sigma$ notation in general? @Lebes

Comment: $$\sum_{f}$$ Means sum of faces.

Comment: Well, it means the sum as $f$ varies over the faces. @Lebes Faces are not numbers, so you can't sum them.

Comment: Yes ok. So what does :

$v$ on $f$ mean?

Comment: What do *you* think it would mean for a vertex to be on a face?

Comment: You really really need to stop worrying about the $\Sigma$ notation, and instead think about that matrix above. The $\Sigma$ notation assumed a level of ease of reading mathematics that you do not yet have. Instead, think about the matrix above. How would you add the values in that matrix? Do you understand what is in that matrix?

Answer (score 2):

What the proof essentially shows is that any valid arrangement that satisfies the incidence requirement must have a sum at least 40; therefore, no arrangement with a sum of 39 is possible without violating the incidence requirement.  The proof does not explicitly construct an arrangement with a sum of 39, because there are in general a very large number of such arrangements, and in order to show that all of them violate the incidence requirement (i.e., there exist two faces of equal value that share a vertex), you would have to enumerate them exhaustively.  That's inefficient.

Your question, therefore, isn't really the most pertinent one to ask:  it merely suffices to show that any valid arrangement of numbers must have a sum strictly greater than 39.  There are arrangements with sum greater than 40, for example.  If two faces of such an arrangement have the same number and share a vertex, **that does not guarantee the sum will be less than 40**.  For example, choose all the faces to have the value 1000.

For those interested in the geometry of the problem, it should be noted that the twenty faces of the icosahedron can be matched into five groups of four faces, such that each group does not share a vertex among any of its faces (the faces in a group are disjoint), and that each vertex is incident to exactly one face from each group.  For each group, draw an edge from the center of each face to the center of the other faces.  These edges then form five regular tetrahedra and the resulting compound of five tetrahedra comes in two enantiomorphs.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Those animations are beautiful.  How did you make them?

Comment: @JoshKeneda They were made using *Mathematica* version 9.  If there is interest, I can add the code to my answer; however, I don't want to stray off topic from the question that was originally asked.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to look into Mathematica sometime...