# Complete Solution (Icosahedron Proof Putnam)

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, analysis, geometry, contest-math

I posted a similar question earlier, but then I noted an issue. Again the problem:

**A1:**

> Recall that a regular icosahedron is a convex polyhedron having 12 vertices and 20 faces; the faces are congruent equilateral triangles. On each face of a regular icosahedron is written a nonnegative integer such that the sum of all integers written on the $20$ faces is $39.$ Show that there are two faces that share a vertex having the same integer written on them.

Then G. Eric. Moorehouse's solution:

[image]

**I modified the diagram to fit his answer:**

[image]

The problem is with the red region. Look at the **Third R**. It shares vertex with $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ hence it cannot get any of the numbers? Isn't that an issue as he does:

$$4(0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4) ?? $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is not trying to show how to get to 40 exactly, he is trying to show that you get at least 40. His use of "minimal possible" is a bit of a poor choice of words - he's really showing a lower bound, not how to actually achieve 40.

Here's a solution that actually achieves $40$, however.

[image]

I still think [my answer to the original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1204555/7933) is way clearer than Moorhouse's answer.

Comment: Thanks! Without doing this, how can he predict that the sum will be ≥40? 

Also, he considered there case where two sides dont share a vertex. What about when $\ge 3$ faces share the number (with the same vertex)? Wouldn't that be the second case? Thanks!